# gcc and g++ are installed but ubuntu says they are not installed

Tags: 12.04, gcc, g++

I have installed g++ and gcc from repository on ubuntu 12.04 ad you can see that they are indeed installed

```
mahmood@pc:~$ dpkg -l | grep gcc
ii  gcc-4.4                                4.4.7-1ubuntu2                          GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.4-base                           4.4.7-1ubuntu2                          GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.4-multilib                       4.4.7-1ubuntu2                          GNU C compiler (multilib files)
ii  gcc-4.6-base                           4.6.3-1ubuntu5                          GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  lib32gcc1                              1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                        GCC support library (32 bit Version)
ii  libgcc1                                1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                        GCC support library
ii  libgcc1-dbg                            1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                        GCC support library (debug symbols)

mahmood@pc:~$ dpkg -l | grep g++
ii  g++-4.4                                4.4.7-1ubuntu2                          GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-4.4-multilib                       4.4.7-1ubuntu2                          GNU C++ compiler (multilib files)
```

However when I run `gcc` or `g++` commands, it says they are not installed

```
mahmood@pc:~$ g++
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

mahmood@pc:~$ gcc
The program 'gcc' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcc
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

What did I miss??

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with Eclipse. The command eclipse cannot find the installed program. I thought this might be an issue with setting the PATH variable but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the packages `gcc` and `g++` installed.

This packages contain the files `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` while the package `gcc-4.4` contains `/usr/bin/gcc-4.4` and the package `g++-4.4` contains `/usr/bin/g++-4.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Eclipse. It was solved by adding a symbolic link in the `/usr/local/bin folder`.
So first change to the folder: `cd /usr/local/bin`
then add a symbolic link: `ln -s <folder where actual program is located>`.